# Serializing a scala object into a JSon String using lift-json

Tags: json, scala, lift

I am wondering, would you please let me know how can I use lift-json to serialize a simple bean class into json string (I'm using v2.0-M1).
I tried:

```
val r = JsonDSL.pretty(JsonAST.render(myBean))
```

and I am getting

```
[error]  found   : MyBean
[error]  required: net.liftweb.json.JsonAST.JValue
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can "decompose" a case class into JSON and then render it. Example:

```
scala> import net.liftweb.json.JsonAST._
scala> import net.liftweb.json.Extraction._
scala> import net.liftweb.json.Printer._    
scala> implicit val formats = net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats

scala> case class MyBean(name: String, age: Int)
scala> pretty(render(decompose(MyBean("joe", 35))))
res0: String = 
{
  "name":"joe",
  "age":35
}
```

But sometimes it is easier to use DSL syntax:

```
scala> import net.liftweb.json.JsonDSL._
scala> val json = ("name" -> "joe") ~ ("age" -> 35)
scala> pretty(render(json))
res1: String = 
{
  "name":"joe",
  "age":35
}
```

Comment: What if it's not a case class?

Comment: With liftweb 3.1.0 this has moved from pretty(render()) to prettyRender().  You can also do compactRender().  Both are part of net.liftweb.json.JsonAST._