# How to pass optional parameter in gson in scala spark

Tags: scala, parsing, gson

I have the following case class.

```
case class STUDENT(studentName:String,marks:Array[String],gender:String,mobileNumber:Option[String])
```

and i have the following Json string.

```
"studentName": "test_filter",
"marks":"['10','20']",
"gender":"M",
"mobileNumber": "*****"
```

and the below function that parse the string,actual i am passing json as string.

```
 def readStudentConfig(config:String) :STUDENT ={
   val gson = new Gson()
    gson.fromJson(config,classOf[STUDENT])
  }
```

But its return me an error like

> ```
> Failed to invoke public scala.Option() with no args
> ```

Edit question for better understanding.

and i have the following Json string.If i pass the mobileNumber the parser is working(need to **change datatype case class last paramter to String**)

```
{ 
"studentName": "test_filter",
"marks":"['10','20']",
"gender":"M",
"mobileNumber": "*****"
```

}

If i blank the mobileNumber i.e "mobileNumber":''; the code will break. like that

```
    { 
    "studentName": "test_filter",
    "marks":"['10','20']",
    "gender":"M",
    "mobileNumber": "" 
   }
```

Comment: Don't use Gson for Scala: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gson%2bscala?tab=Newest .

Comment: I need to pass dynamic config file.that was an example maily i need to know how to passoptional paramter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gson optional and required fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626690/gson-optional-and-required-fields)

Comment: No . can i Pass json like {"user_id":128591, "user_name":""} in your mention comment where username may or may not be blank @RamanMishra

Comment: @user3841003 That's what optional means right? either it can be blank or it can have value. Try giving default value as None for mobile_number field.

Comment: @RamanMishra i have tried same but same error is coming.

Comment: look this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785465/how-can-i-use-gson-in-scala-to-serialize-a-list/8415907#8415907`