# Converting to net.liftweb.json.JsonAST.JObject Lift in Scala

Tags: scala, lift, lift-json

I am trying to construct a JSON object from a list where key is "products" and value is List[Product] where Product is a case class.But I am getting error that says "type mismatch; found : (String, List[com.mycompnay.ws.client.Product]) required: net.liftweb.json.JObject (which expands to) net.liftweb.json.JsonAST.JObject".

What I have done so far is as below:

```
val resultJson:JObject = "products" -> resultList
      println(compact(render(resultJson)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `decompose` ([doc](https://liftweb.net/api/30/api/index.html#net.liftweb.json.Extraction$@decompose(a:Any)(implicitformats:net.liftweb.json.Formats):net.liftweb.json.JValue)). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223079/4642274).

I tested the following code and it worked fine:

```scala
import net.liftweb.json._
import net.liftweb.json.JsonDSL._
import net.liftweb.json.Extraction._

implicit val formats = net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats

case class Product(foo: String)

val resultList: List[Product] = List(Product("bar"), Product("baz"))
val resultJson: JObject = ("products" -> decompose(resultList))
println(compact(render(resultJson)))
```

Result:

```js
{"products":[{"foo":"bar"},{"foo":"baz"}]}
```

Comment: Yes,that perfectly helps.Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Sakalya I'm glad I could help. Please consider accepting this answer if there are no better answers after some time. Thanks :)